# NATIVESCRIPT + JS add marker to map with button

Tags: javascript, nativescript, google-maps-android-api-2

how can i select mymap by id and then add the marker ?

```
function addMarker(args){
        var MyMapById; // i dont know how to bind mymaps to this variable
        MyMapById.clear();
        var marker = new mapsModule.Marker();
        marker.position = mapsModule.Position.positionFromLatLng(latitude, longitude);
        MyMapById.addMarker(marker);
    }
```

here is my xml page:

```
<Page 
    xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
    xmlns:maps="nativescript-google-maps-sdk"
    navigatedTo="onNavigatedTo">
    <GridLayout rows="auto, *">
        <Button text="Add Marker" tap="addMarker" />

        <maps:mapView latitude="{{ latitude }}" longitude="{{ longitude }}" row="1" id="mymap"  
         mapAnimations="false" cameraChanged="onCameraChanged" zoom="12" mapReady="onMapReady" />
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be able to get reference to any component on the page with getViewById method, for instance `page.getViewById("mymap")`